# String compare in Scala

Tags: string, scala, scalatest

I have a method that returns a String.

```
public String getDBValue(arg1)
```

The output of this method can either be `"cat"` or `"dog"`

I am writing a test case in scala and I normally use this -

```
getDBValue(arg1) shouldBe "cat"
```

How do I check for the string being either `"cat"` or `"dog"`

Comment: I get this -------"dog" did not contain at least one of ("cat", "dog")
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: "dog" did not contain at least one of ("cat", "dog")

Comment: I was wrong, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `getDBValue(arg1) should (equal "cat" or equal "dog")`

Check this page for reference: 

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#logicalExpressions

Answer (score 0):

As for pure Scala String compare (not ScalaTest) you may use:

```
Set("cat", "dog").contains(getDBValue(arg1))
```